# Add data and display into data table in HTML page from web service using AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I want add and display data into data table plugin from webservice using ajax call,but don't know how to catch data

HTML page:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var realPath = "http://localhost:8080";
      var webServicePathm = realPath + "/mt/gj/jg?";
      //var project = projectname.innerText;
      var parmUrl = "tenantid=XYZ";
      var webCallUrl = webServicePathm + parmUrl;

      var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            "ajax": ({
              type: "GET",
              url: webCallUrl,
              data: {},
              datatype: 'json',
              complete: function(data) {
                var objdata = JSON.stringify(data);
              },
              error: function() {

              }

            }),
```

Comment: You did not post any HTML. Nor any console errors or other information that can help us. Please create a [mcve] - you can start with `console.log(objdata)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you want but try to change code with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var realPath = "http://localhost:8080";
      var webCallUrl = realPath + "/mt/saasreporting/getopenticketssummary";
      //var project = projectname.innerText;
      var str = "XYZ";
      var var_data = "tenantid="+str;

      var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            "ajax": ({
              type: "POST",
              url: webCallUrl,
              data: var_data,
              datatype: 'json',
              complete: function(data) {
                var objdata = JSON.stringify(data);
              },
              error: function() {

              }

            }),
```

Comment: Welcome:) Please accept answer if you think it's working

Answer (score 0):

In the main documentation of `DataTable`, you need to pass the object that contains the `json` to the `ajax` attribute. Here is the example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "data/arrays.txt"
    } );
} );
```

Where data that is send to ajax:

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      "Donna Snider",
      "Customer Support",
      "New York",
      "4226",
      "2011/01/25",
      "$112,000"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Here is [link](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html) to the official documentation.